# table overwritten

Tags: tables, apa6

I am using an APA 6 version for journal articles. The APA splits the page in two. How can I have the table not been overwritten for the text (see image)?

[image]

I am usign the following code:

```
\documentclass[jou,apacite]{apa6}

\usepackage{rotating} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\begin{document}
TEXT....

\begin{table}

\begin{adjustbox}{width=1\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{ccccccccccccc}\\ \toprule

 TABLE CONTENT....

\end{tabular}

\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}
 MORE TEXT...
```

Comment: Does a `table*` instead of `table` work? Adjustbox is almost certainly the wrong way.

Comment: avioid scaling tables in general but here you are forcing the table to be \textwidth wide, so more than twice as wide as wide as the column.

Comment: since "Furthermore" starts a new paraghraph you can add a `\vspace*{80pt}` (play with the value) at the and of previous paragraph and solve the problem... But this has to be done when everything is ready because a change in the paragraphs will cause problems...

Comment: @TeXnician do you mean using \begin{table*}? I deleted the adjustbox command as you suggest!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle certantly I am forcing the table size to fit into the margins. I don't know other way of doing it.

Comment: you want it to fit to column width (for `table`) or use a spanning `table*` if you want it for text width, but scaling the table should be the absolute last resort, you would not justify a parargaph by scaling the text to arbitrary size. If for example you decide to go for a single column table you will need to change the layout, just scaling it to the column width will make it unreadably small.